# What is wrong with this code? It won't run

Tags: java, arrays, stack

```
public class StackSimple{
    private   long  capacity=1000;//maximum size of array
    private int idx_top;
    private Object data[];

    public StackSimple(int capacity)
    {
        idx_top=-1;
        this.capacity=capacity;
        data = new Object[capacity];
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return(idx_top<0);

    }
    public boolean isFull(){
        return(idx_top>=capacity-1);
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return idx_top+1;
    }

    public boolean push(Object x){
        if (isFull()){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("ERROR:Stack Overflow.Full Stack");
}
        else
        {`enter code here`data[++idx_top]=x;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Object pop(){
        if(isEmpty())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("ERROR:Stack Underflow.Empty Stack.");
        else{
            return data[idx_top--];
        }
}

public Object top(){
    if (isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("ERROR:Stack Underflow.Empty Stack.");
    else{
        return data[idx_top];
   }
}

public void print()
{`
for (int i=size()-1;i>=0;i--)
        System.out.println(data[i]);
}



}

public class Stack_Exercise {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StackSimple s = new  StackSimple(capacity:3);//error shows here
        s.push(x:"books");`enter code here`
        s.push(x:"something");
        s.push(x:"200");
        s.print();
        System.out.println("Size=" +s.size());
    }
}
```

Why doesn't this work?
 Why does it say invalid statement while creating the StackSimple object? The problem is in the main class while running it. There are errors while pushing the elements.

[Error while compiling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfTOi.jpg)

Comment: `new  StackSimple(capacity:3)` ??  Just `new  StackSimple(3)`. Are you using IntelliJ by chance ?

Comment: Put your error message instead of a picture.

Comment: what does this mean to you?: ***StackSimple(capacity:3);***

Comment: (What it means to me is that someone needs to re-read his notes on how to call a method.  That is NOT valid Java syntax)

Comment: @Rakshya I have added below my recommendation, please vote...

Answer (score 0):

When passing parameters to a function you just pass the values. 
In your case not `StackSimple(capacity:3)` but just `StackSimple(3)`

Answer (score 0):

First question, which version of Java are you using.

Second, in Java you should be passing as a variable instead of StackSimple(capacity:3). Change your main method to below, here is my recommendation:

```
    StackSimple s = new  StackSimple(3);
    s.push("books");
    s.push("something");
    s.push("200");
    s.print();
    System.out.println("Size=" +s.size());
```

Comment: I am using java 8. This code was provided by our lecturer. i tried to study and run it but could not.

Answer (score 0):

You are not at all pushing the value in the stack, your pusch function is not working as it is expected to work.

Here is the correct program.

```
class StackSimple {
    private long capacity = 1000;// maximum size of array
    private int idx_top;
    private Object data[];

    public StackSimple(int capacity) {
        idx_top = -1;
        this.capacity = capacity;
        data = new Object[capacity];
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (idx_top < 0);

    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        return (idx_top >= capacity - 1);
    }

    public int size() {
        return idx_top + 1;
    }

    public boolean push(Object x) {
        if (isFull()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("ERROR:Stack Overflow.Full Stack");
        } else {
            data[++idx_top] = x;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Object pop() {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("ERROR:Stack Underflow.Empty Stack.");
        else {
            return data[idx_top--];
        }
    }

    public Object top() {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("ERROR:Stack Underflow.Empty Stack.");
        else {
            return data[idx_top];
        }
    }

    public void print() {
        for (int i = size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            System.out.println(data[i]);
    }

}

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StackSimple s = new StackSimple(3);// error shows here
        s.push("books");
        s.push("something");
        s.push("200");
        s.print();
        System.out.println("Size=" + s.size());
    }
}
```